# Compiling problems using linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, compilation

So I'm attempting to compiling a program using the linux command line. I'm using linux through a virtual machine. I compile using

```
gcc -lm calc.c -o calc
```

where `calc.c` is the source file and I'm compiling with `-lm` because it includes `math.h`. I'll make changes to the source code but it does not reflect when I run. In fact, that line of code does not even produce calc.exe....Help??

Comment: You're saying "it does not reflect when i run." If doesn't even produce an executable, how are you running it?

Comment: `calc` is not the same as `calc.exe`.  Does it create `calc`?

Comment: In Linux you don't put .exe to executables.

Answer (score 2):

> In fact, that line of code does not even produce calc.exe

You need to read up on gcc and Linux, an executable doesn't need any specific extension in Linux it just need executable permissions. (.exe is used on windows)

'gcc -lm calc.c -o calc'

This line will make an executable called `calc` (the name after the `-o` flag is the name of your executable). You run it with:

`./calc`

You can verify that it's executable via `ls -l calc`, you'll see something like this:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 [owner/group names] [file size] [date you built] [time you built] calc
```

The x's in the output mean it's executable.

Comment: nevermind im dumb. Thanks for the help. It turns out there was an error in my code which led it to not compile. Didnt read it all the way through...lol

Comment: @CalvinS - gottcha. ;) it happens

Comment: @CalvinS: The `./` prefix is important; without it, if you happen to have a program called `calc` somewhere in your `$PATH`, you could execute that rather than your program. (Test programs named `test` are a common source of this error.) And if your code didn't compile, you should have gotten an error message from the compiler.

Comment: A bit of a side note: You can also type `file calc` and get some output about what kind of file it is.